# Interpreting results from lightFM

Tags: svm, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, matrix-factorization

I built a recommendation model on a user-item transactional dataset where each transaction is represented by 1.

```
model = LightFM(learning_rate=0.05, loss='warp')
```

Here are the results

```
Train precision at k=3:  0.115301
Test precision at k=3:  0.0209936

Train auc score:  0.978294
Test auc score : 0.810757

Train recall at k=3:  0.238312330233
Test recall at k=3:  0.0621618086561
```

Can anyone help me interpret this result? How is it that I am getting such good auc score and such bad precision/recall? The precision/recall gets even worse for 'bpr' Bayesian personalized ranking.

Prediction task

```
users = [0]
items = np.array([13433, 13434, 13435, 13436, 13437, 13438, 13439, 13440])
model.predict(users, item)
```

Result

```
array([-1.45337546, -1.39952552, -1.44265926, -0.83335167, -0.52803332,
   -1.06252205, -1.45194077, -0.68543684])
```

How do I interpret the prediction scores?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the difference between precision@K at AUC, you may want to have a look at my answer here: [Evaluating the LightFM Recommendation Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451161/evaluating-the-lightfm-recommendation-model/45466481#45466481).

The scores themselves do not have a defined scale and are not interpretable. They only make sense in the context of defining a ranking over items for a given user, with higher scores denoting a stronger predicted preference.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to get rates as predictions? I mean, if we give rates (between 1 and 10) to the model to train, how can we get the same kind of output? Thanks